# Joint PDF of Uniform Independent events

Tags: probability, density-function

If X and Y are uniform independent random variables, X~(0,30) and Y~(40,50). I want to know how to find the joint PDF.?

I tried doing it on a rectangle, but i get stuck with the entries. Can u suggest how to proceed?

Comment: You said: "I tried doing it on a rectangle, but i get stuck with the entries." What do you mean? Can you show us exactly what you tried and where you got stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** If two random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent then

$$f_X(x)\cdot f_Y(y)=f_{X,Y}(x,y) \quad \forall  \ x,y \in \mathbb R$$

$f_X(x)$ is the pdf of $X$. Similar for $f_Y(y)$. And $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is the joint probability distribution function of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Yup, That helped alot! Thanks :)

Comment: @ChongSu You´re welcome.